# editor.codeActionsOnSave's source.organeImports not working in vscode's dev containers

Tags: python, vscode-extensions, vscode-devcontainer

I've been using the following vscode settings well with wsl and vscode:

```
{
  "[python]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": true
    },
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  }
}
```

but when I'm trying to develop using dev containers with the following customizations.vscode.settings in devcontainers.json:

```
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
  },
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

organizeImports doesn't seem to work as intended, but formatOnSave and Type seems to work fine. Did I miss something?

I tried fiddling with Preferences: Remote Settings (JSON) (Dev Container: {my container}) to no avail.